# Access Views inside custom UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, tableview, xib, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is populated by the cells coming from another XIB file. How can I access the views (eg. label) of the cell inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of tableView?

Comment: You can access the cell by calling `tableView.dequeReusableCellForIndexPath()` and access the `textLabel`.

Comment: I can access all the properties of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I want to change the color of the label when cell gets selected. That, I don't know how to get that particular cell and then label of that cell.

Comment: You can call this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
```

then you can access its label:

```
cell.customLabel.text = "test"
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me hint. Though I am working in objective-C, this gave me good hint. The only thing which I added is to type cast this cell with that XIB where I define this custom cell. Thanks.

Comment: I’m glad that helped you :)